# Given a vector space $V$ and if $U_1, U_2$ are two subspaces of $V$. I can't find $U_1, U_2$ so that $U_1 \cup U_2$ is not a subspace of V.

Tags: linear-algebra

What I know is that if $U_1, U_2$ are two linear subspaces of the same $F$ vector space $V$, then $U_1 \cup U_2$ is also a linear subspace of $V \space$ if $\space U_1 \subset U_2$ or $U_2 \subset U_1$.

Could someone find an example of a $F$ vector space $V$, with two linear subspaces $U_1$ respectively $U_2$, such that $F, V, U_1, U_2$ have infinitely many elements and $U_1 \cup U_2$ is not a linear subspace of $V$?

I was motivated to ask this because of what I read in the pdf I found about linear algebra, more specifically this passage:
[image: Lemma, the statement is fenced by the red rectangle]

I fenced the statement with a red rectangle but also left the original lemma in the picture for more context.

[You can find the pdf here!](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/lecture-notes/LinearAlgebraI.pdf)

The chapter, from which the passage is extracted, is "Linear Subspace and Linear Hulls".

Comment: Take $\mathbb R^2$ and let one linear subspace be the $x-$axis, and let the other be the $y-$axis.

Comment: Do you mean infinitely many elements or infinite dimensions? Every non-trivial vector space over an infinite field has infinite elements.

Comment: @K.Power No I don't mean infinite dimensions, I mean infinite elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be the vector space of the $x,y$ plane. This has subspaces $x$ axis and $y$ axis, but the union of these is not a subspace. (has $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in it but not their sum $(1,1).$

Note here each of $F,$ $x,$ $y$ axis has infinitely many elements.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, $F=\Bbb Q$, $V=\Bbb Q^2$, $U_1=\{(q,0)\,:\, q\in\Bbb Q\}$, $U_2=\{(0,q)\,:\, q\in\Bbb Q\}$.

Comment: Isn't $U_1 \cup U_2  = V$? I mean $U_1 \cup U_2 = \{(q_1, q_2) : q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, right?

Comment: No and no.${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Consider *any* pair of subspaces such that neither in contained in the other,  take $u_1\in U_1\smallsetminus U_2$, $u_2\in U_2\smallsetminus U_1$.

If $\;U_1\cup U_2$ were a subspace, $u_1+u_2$ would be  in $U_1\cup U_2$. Where would it live? $U_1$ or $U_2$?

Comment: Where does $V_2$ come from?

Comment: A typo. I'll fix it  at once. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! As with your hint I state that if $U_1 \cup U_2$ is a subspace then $U_1 \subset U_2$ or $U_2 \subset U_1$ so this concludes to $u_1 + u_2 \in U_2$ if it's the first case or $u_1 + u_2 \in U_1$ if it's the latter.

Comment: Actually we obtain a contradiction in each case: if $u_1+u_2\in U_1$, then $u_2=(u_1+u_2)-u_1\in U_1$, and similarly if it's in $U_2$, we obtain $u_1\in U_2$.

Comment: Oh and also what I've written doesn't quite make sense when doing the operations $U_1 ∖ U_2$ when $U_1 \subset U_2$ and $U_2 ∖ U_1$ when $U_2 \subset U_1$. Also is the contradiction the fact that $u_1 + u_2$ could be outside of $U_1$ and $U_2$?

Comment: The contradiction, intuitively, lies in the fact  that $u_1+u_2$ has to lie  in $U_1\cup U_2$ if the latter is supposed to be a subspace, but it can't be in any of its components.